# Possible to configure Apache2 Virtualhosts to looks for files in a directory based on hostname?

Tags: apache-2.2, virtualhost

Pretty much what the title of the question is. On my local machine I've been setting up named virtual hosts for each clients website that I'm working on. It would be quicker if I could specify a wildcard rule that:

> http://[hostname]

refers to files in

> ~/Sites/[hostname]/

Automatically without having to create an entry for each (which I currently have now)

Is this possible?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, you can do this with [mod vhost alias](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_vhost_alias.html).